# Finding $\int_0^1\int_0^1\ldots\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}\ln(x_i)}\,dx_1dx_2\ldots dx_n$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, multiple-integral

I am interested in finding $$f(n) = \int_0^1\int_0^1\ldots\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}\ln(x_i)}\,dx_1dx_2\ldots dx_n$$ for positive integer $n$.

For example, $$f(2)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-\ln(x_1)\ln(x_2)}\,dx_1dx_2$$

I found $f(1) = e \cdot E_1(1) \approx 0.596$, $f(2)$ diverges, $f(3) \approx 0.724$.
$$$$
**My questions**

How can I find $f(n)$ for positive integer $n$?

If that is not possible, what is an approximation?

I know for sure that if $n$ is odd, $f(n)$ converges. This is because $\frac{1}{1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}\ln(x_i)}$ will converge for $0 \le x_i \le 1$. I also suspect that if $n$ is even, $f(n)$ diverges.

Comment: Can you give some background about this integral? Like how did you encounter it and why is it in your  interested? Because it doesn't look easy.

Comment: @ㄴㄱ It just popped into my head after seeing another question that was similar. Unfortunately, I don't remember what that question was.